# Android Google Play Services Broken? isConnected() throws errors

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services, android-sdk-tools

Since updated my SDK Manager packages, my google play services hasn't been working.

This is causing my Samsung S5 Running 5.0, HTC One_M8 running 5.0.1, and my Nexus 5 running 6.0 (the Android M preview) to crash.

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: The method 'boolean com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.isConnected()' was expected to be of type interface but instead was found to be of type virtual (declaration of 'java.lang.reflect.ArtMethod' appears in /system/framework/core-libart.jar)
```

Running the same code on Samsung Mega running 4.4.2 and a Nexus 4 running 4.4.4, I'm getting this error.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.isConnected
```

These errors only started happening after the latest updates from the SDK Manager, I update very regularly and my last update before I noticed the issue was on October 5, 2015.

Current SDK

- Android Support Repository: 21.
- Android Support Library: 23.0.1
- Google Play services: 27
- Android SDK Tools: 24.4
- Android SDK Platform-tools: 23.0.1
- Android SDK Build-tools: 23.0.1

Everything worked perfectly before the update. Is there anyway to fix this? I've spend hours trying to figure out if I screwed up something somewhere, but there have been no changes to my project that involve google play services since the last time it worked. I have confirmed with someone, using the exact same codebase as I'm using (we use git) who hasn't yet updated their SDK packages, that our code still works for him.  I may have to revert my SDK tools since I cannot simply wait around for a possible fix if it is a bug. I get the update is very new but I can't be the only one having this problem....

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: See the last bullet of the September 2015 portion of [the release notes](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases), as that seems to be related to what you're seeing.

Comment: Also check out [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/3mehbb/breaking_changes_in_google_play_services_81/). If you are using a library which also depends on Google Play Services, and the library dependency isn't updated but your own is, it will throw the error you mentioned.

Comment: Thank you so much! This looks like it is indeed my issue. The software I write is a library that other people embed in their applications. We have little control over what version of google play services they use. So it looks like I need to somehow programmatically check which version of GPS in their app they are compiling with now and then have two different classes to support GPS depending on the version?  Is there even a way to do this?  sigh

Comment: If you mention this as a solution I will mark it correct. My last comment is technically another question, and I'm not sure if follow-up questions in comments is considered appropriate on SO. If not I will submit it as another question.  Cheers

Comment: As a reference for anyone else having this issue. 

int gpsVersion= context.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.google_play_services_version);

will return the version code for the compiled google play services version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've found out what my issue truly was. It seamed odd that the isConnected() method in the GoogleApiClient would break while all the other static methods could be called without issue. But when you have an API update that get's announced as a "breaking change" you kind of expect things to not work anymore.

Well on Wednesday Oct 7'th I noticed another update which I've finally had a chance to test and the issue is no longer present. So it looks like this was a bug in their "breaking change". Thankfully Google got this fixed rather quickly. But it works now. So I've essentially reverted my code back to the way it was before. Cheers!

Comment: in my case. i got the becoz of the updated google play services library..i downgraded to  com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'